# How to uninstall https everywhere from Firefox

Tags: firefox, uninstall, https-everywhere

I can't find anywhere to uninstall https everywhere. It's not in the list under Tools. Please tell me the secret. I am using FF on Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Uninstall https? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Which FF version?

Answer (score 2):

HTTPS Everywhere is a Firefox extension.  You should be able to remove from Tools > Add-Ons, then select the Extensions link on the left side, and click Disable and/or Remove.